# Why did one of my textures turn pink?

Tags: shaders

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrMee2gcS20&t=281s) tutorial awhile back and successfully ended up with this image rendered in cycles.

[image: good image of a landscape]

Here's what my node setup looks like.

[image: shader node setup]

Recently, I came back to the scene to render it at a higher resolution. I rendered it and got this image out:

[image: crappy image of a landscape]

Why did the rock and sand textures turn pink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textures turn magenta when the shader fails to locate the image texture assigned to it. Double check the image paths for the rock and sand diffuse textures in the node tree. Reopen the images if it need be.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Reopening all of my images did the trick, thanks!

Comment: You can even save some time. Go to File > External Data > Find Missing files, done @EdwardHurley (also mentioned in the dupe)

Comment: @brockmann thanks!